# Is it possible to create a new type(but not a new class) in Python 1 or Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, types, python-2.x

There is no `object` type in Python 2.1.x or lower.
Here are three files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
class foo: pass
print(foo)
print(repr(foo))
print(type(foo))
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
class foo(object): pass
print(foo)
print(repr(foo))
print(type(foo))
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
class foo(object): pass
print(foo)
print(repr(foo))
print(type(foo))
```

and here is their outputs:(for reference only)

```
__main__.foo
<class __main__.foo at 0xf7d30e9c>
<type 'classobj'>
```

```
<class '__main__.foo'>
<class '__main__.foo'>
<type 'type'>
```

```
<class '__main__.foo'>
<class '__main__.foo'>
<class 'type'>
```

In Python 3, all types are classes.
But in Python 1 and Python 2, types are “type” type, and classes are “classobj” type. And the class generated by `class foo(object): pass` is just a child class from “object” type.
So, Is it possible to create a new type(but not a new class) in Python 1 or Python 2? If it is, how?

Comment: No, that's why new-style classes were added: to eliminate the artificial distinction between classes and types. *Old-style* classes have type `classobj`, but they were effectively deprecated as soon as new-style classes were introduced in Python 2.2. Given the extreme age of the versions being asked about, this would probably be more suitable https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)

> No, that's why new-style classes were added: to eliminate the artificial distinction between classes and types. Old-style classes have type `classobj`, but they were effectively deprecated as soon as new-style classes were introduced in Python 2.2. Given the extreme age of the versions being asked about, this would probably be more suitable retrocomputing.stackexchange.com.